# Difference between ThreadPool Items?

Tags: c#, threadpool

Are they same meaning?

And How should I use  `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(20, 20);` because I can not see 20 thread working asynchronously?

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(20, 20);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(WorkThread), DateTime.Now);
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(WorkThread), DateTime.Now);
        }
```

Comment: Btw, you start 10 things, not 20

Comment: "Are they same meaning"? What "they" are you asking about here? The difference between a threadpool item and ...?

Comment: Ok I wrote wrong. Numbers will be same. They are code,and I am asking , Are they doing same work?

Answer (score 4):

How many threads the pool uses is largely up to it, and may vary based on what ***else*** is going on, the number of unstarted items, etc; you are only setting the ***max***. You aren't the only user of the pool; .net uses that itself, so don't mess with it. If you explicitly want 20 threads, create 20 `Thread`s.

Comment: Actually, my aim is:
creating a program for 100 user(I mean thread) asynchronously , this threads run some codes and I want to calculate taking how many time. So I am using wrong way with threadpool?

Comment: @user - indeed, I wouldnt use te pool for that, but I wouldn't want thread per user either; a manual queue with a low number of workers is usually preferred

Answer (score 1):

ThreadPool is implemented differently in .NET 4 (as opposed to .NET).

When you set Max ThreadPool, you are saying how many you want threadPool to create *if* required. If queued task is quick, it might be able to process it even with couple of them without creating 20 Threads.

You could set SetMinThreads, that will ensure that it creates minimum number of threads first. But be careful on this, as creating threads is resources hit

[see MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)